# Distributed system with many containers but only one runs the client SPA

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

Currently, I have to applications running one is a Web API to support multiple clients and the other is a react SPA that is a Management client application that consumes the Web API mentioned before.
The Web API is hosted on AWS using docker containers and deployed through ECS Fargate tasks. The SPA is deployed in the same way but in a different ECS cluster.
What I want is to know if it is possible to merge these applications into one single project. (By the way, I'm coding with ASP.NET core 2.2) and only run the SPA if doesn't exist an instance of it already. e.g I deployed my Web API for the first time so there is no instance SPA client running the Web API will launch the SPA. After a while a deploy a second container the instance already exists the API won't launch another SPA.

Comment: you can add the SPA container into the same task definition of you web api. so, 2 containers in a single task definition.
or if you want to have different autoscaling for the 2, you can add 2 task definitions to the cluster.

Comment: I thought of that but would still be two separate application and I still have to deal with CORS and other situations @MuhammadHasan

Comment: If you want your dot net app to control the deployment of your SPA, then you should consider AWS sdk for dot net core https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/ . You'll be able to control the SPA cluster management from your dot net core app.

Comment: Felipe: No problem merging two apps into one. I would recommend an upgrade to Core 3.1 as well, else you will fall behind. We're soon at Core 5.